# boost::core::demangle on visual studio typeid().name

Tags: c++, windows, boost, demangler

i'm trying to get a string reporting a class type without decoration on windows (visual studio 2010) with no success at all.

Since UnDecorateName does not work i'm using boost libraries.

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <boost/core/demangle.hpp>

class MyObject{};

int main (int argc,  char ** argv)
{
    MyObject o;
    const char * str = typeid(o).name(); // str = "class MyObject"
    std::string dstr = boost::core::demangle( str ); // dstr = "class MyObject"

    return 0;
}
```

How can i get only "MyObject" as an output string from the code above?
Right now i can't use c++11 methods.

Comment: how about some simple string manipulation (i.e. remove the first 6 characters)?

Comment: It does not work in all cases. eg: int *.

Comment: Just look for keywords class/struct/union/enum and remove them from the string.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE** Sadly this library uses the same underlying demangling API under the hood: see comment by @cv_and_he

You could try the newer TypeIndex library:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/000b138dac3f7ee1)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/type_index.hpp>
#include <iostream>

class MyObject { public: virtual ~MyObject() {} };
struct Derived : MyObject {};

int main() {
    MyObject o;
    Derived d;

    std::cout << boost::typeindex::type_id<MyObject>().pretty_name() << "\n";
    std::cout << boost::typeindex::type_id<Derived>().pretty_name() << "\n";

    MyObject& r = d;
    std::cout << boost::typeindex::type_id_runtime(r).pretty_name() << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
MyObject
Derived
Derived
```

On my compilers

Comment: Cool. I didn't know there were any boost-capable online compilers